# Remove leading 0 in time in PHP?

Tags: php

Suppose I have the time `11:00 am` ($getOpen) and another time as `12:30 am`($getClose). I want to output the following:

`11am - 12:30pm`

How can I do that in PHP?

I tried to use the following code but it does not work:

```
if ($getOpen[-4] == '0' && $getOpen[-5] == '0') {
    substr_replace($getOpen, "", -4, strlen($getOpen));
}

if ($getClose[-4] == '0' && $getClose[-5] == '0') {
    substr_replace($getOpen, "", -4, strlen($getClose));
}
```

Comment: Use [the `date()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to output in the desired format. Use [`date_parse_from_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) to convert into a date object, if [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `str_replace`.

```
$getOpen = str_replace(':00 ', '', $getOpen);
```